# Flexbox text and span cell not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox, less

Trying to utilize Flexbox more and had referred to some items on the web, but for the likes of me, am not getting it to layout as I would have hoped and tried.

What I have now is this:
[image]

These should span the full width as indicated by the black lines and space evenly. Additionally, am trying to get the text to justify center to the span since the span is just a colored dot as shown.

```css
.section-copy {
  .column-10;
  .center;
  margin-top: @column-gutter * 2;
}

.section-infomatic {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.infomatic-item {
  padding: 5px;
}

.dot {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section section-map">
  <div class="section-headline centered">Where does interest in stories originate and how do stories spread in the United States?</div>
  <div class="section-copy">
    <p>Search interest generally stems from the larger metro regions. Sports related news usually peaks around the home cities of related teams, while news events with an area-of-effect (like natural disasters) peak in those areas. For example, search interest
      around the 2017 solar eclipse followed the arc of the eclipse movement through the country.</p>
    <p>The peaks in the graphs can tell us whether a topic resonates more in liberal or conservative areas. For example, searches on “US holidays” peak in places like West Virginia, while searches on the “Met Gala” peak in liberal metropolitan centers like
      New York and Los Angeles.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section-copy">
    <div class="section-infomatic">
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot lightgreen"></span>Politics & Elections
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot hotpink"></span>Natural Catastrophes
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot ordorange"></span>Entertainment & Sports
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-infomatic">
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot tealish"></span>Environment & Science
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot orange"></span>Social Issues
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot purpish"></span>War & Violence
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chart chart-map"></div>
</section>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below. I have documented in the source.

```css
.section-copy {
 /*  .column-10;
  .center;
  margin-top: @column-gutter * 2; */
}

.section-infomatic {
  display: flex; /* Instead of inline-flex */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; /* Instead of center */
  align-items: center;
}

.infomatic-item {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1; /* Added */
  display: flex; /* Added */
  align-items: center; /* Added, vertical alignment */
}

.dot {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue; /* For visibility only */
}
```

```html
<section class="section section-map">
  <div class="section-headline centered">Where does interest in stories originate and how do stories spread in the United States?</div>
  <div class="section-copy">
    <p>Search interest generally stems from the larger metro regions. Sports related news usually peaks around the home cities of related teams, while news events with an area-of-effect (like natural disasters) peak in those areas. For example, search interest
      around the 2017 solar eclipse followed the arc of the eclipse movement through the country.</p>
    <p>The peaks in the graphs can tell us whether a topic resonates more in liberal or conservative areas. For example, searches on “US holidays” peak in places like West Virginia, while searches on the “Met Gala” peak in liberal metropolitan centers like
      New York and Los Angeles.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section-copy">
    <div class="section-infomatic">
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot lightgreen"></span>Politics & Elections
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot hotpink"></span>Natural Catastrophes
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot ordorange"></span>Entertainment & Sports
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-infomatic">
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot tealish"></span>Environment & Science
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot orange"></span>Social Issues
      </div>
      <div class="infomatic-item">
        <span class="dot purpish"></span>War & Violence
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chart chart-map"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I just use `width: 100%;` on the items inside the flexbox.